# OS X - how to coerce python3 to use tkinter 8.6

Tags: macos, python-3.x, tkinter

python3 (3.6, installed today) reports that it is using Tcl/Tk version 8.5.  I want to use 8.6.

This is a Macbook Pro Retina running OS X 10.12.  "which python" shows:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3

There are 2 different high level folders including Tcl (and parallel ones for Tk):

1. /Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework

   Under ./Versions

   ```
   8.6 [installed today] and Current (links to 8.6)
   ```
2. /System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework

   Under ./Versions:

   ```
   8.4, 8.5, and Current (links to 8.5)
   ```

There is also miscellaneous stuff under:

3. /Library/Tcl/teapot/package/macosx105.-i386-86-64
4. /System/Library/Tcl/8.4
5. /System/Library/Tcl/8.5

How do I (1) get python3 to use Tk 8.6; and (2) clean up this confusing assortment?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the latest python3 was actually installed under /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0, and tcl-tk under /usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.6.  There is a link from /usr/local/opt/python3 to /usr/local/Cellar/python3, and a corresponding one for tcl-tk.  So a workaround is to just add /usr/local/opt/python3 to PATH.